# Discriminant of $ax^2+bx+c$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Consider $f = ax^2+bx+c \in k[x]$ for some field $k$. The discriminant according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) and several posts here is supposed to be $\Delta(f) = b^2-4ac$ but given that res$(f,f')=$ res$(ax^2+bx+c,2ax+b) = \Delta(f)$ which is $-a(b^2-4ac).$ Obviously if $a=0$ the polynomial is of degree 1 and not 2. Do I get something wrong?

Comment: This is correct. To have degree $2$ , we must have $a\ne 0$ , hence res is $0$ if and only if the discriminant is.

Comment: @Peter but why is the factor $-a$ missing on most sources?

Comment: The discriminant is in fact only $b^2-4ac$

Comment: @Peter so you divide by the leading coefficient by convention or why?

Comment: The definition of the discriminant uses the roots (although it can also be expressed via the coefficients). res(f,g) is something different allowing us to determine whether the polynomials $f$ and $g$ have a common root and in the case $f'=g$ whether $f$ has a root with multiplicity larger than $1$.

Comment: See the discriminant formula in terms of the resultant [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Definition).

Comment: @J.G. that would seem to be an answer to the question - would you care to record it as such below?

Comment: @KReiser OK, done.

Comment: @J.G. maybe I should have been more clear. For example in Using Algebraic Geometry by Cox et al. they define it for $f\in\mathbb C[x]$ as $\Delta(f)=$ Res$(f,f')$ in Chapter 7 additional exercises for §5. That way, I get to $\Delta(ax^2+bx+c)=-a(b^2−4ac)$. May be I should look at a proof connecting the standard method and the resultant method.

Comment: My answer gets the usual $b^2-4ac$, but I'm not an expert on different discriminant conventions for polynomials of arbitrary degree. All I know is they'll each have their own advantages.

Answer (score 3):

A degree-$n>0$ polynomial $f$ of leading coefficient $a_n$ [has discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Definition)$$\Delta=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}\operatorname{res}(f,\,f')/a_n,$$which is nonzero iff $\operatorname{res}(f,\,f')$ is. In this case $n=2,\,a_n=a$, so $\Delta=-\operatorname{res}(f,\,f')/a$.